# web2py ajax calls wrong function

Tags: ajax, web2py

I have a web2py form in which I cannot seem to get an ajax call to work. The form uses datatables, but I don't think that's the problem. Here is the html in the form that makes an ajax call:

```
<a href='#' onclick="ajax('ajax_test', [], 'target')">[ Ajax test ]</a>
</div>
<div id = "target"></div>
```

The ajax_test function simply returns a string.

When I click on the [ Ajax test ] link, the function ajax_test does not execute. Instead, the function that called this form is called, with 'ajax_test' appended to request.args.

There clearly is something I don't understand about web2py and ajax, but I've used it successfully elsewhere and can't figure out why the wrong function is called from this html. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a relative URL in the `ajax` function, which simply appends to the URL of the current page. Assuming this is in a web2py view file, you should use the `URL` function to generate a proper URL:

```
<a href='#' onclick="ajax('{{=URL('default', 'ajax_test')}}', [], 'target')">[ Ajax test ]</a>
```

Comment: Perfecto. Thank you, Anthony. (For this and everything you do for web2py!) I knew this was something simple. Still learning...